# ANT delete empty directories or with index.html file

Tags: php, eclipse, ant

i'm building a free and a pro package with Ant.
In the pro version, there aren't some files, since i can skip them using a custom PhpDoc tag.

Sadly, using this system i have some empty dirs with only a `index.html` and i'd wish to delete them, so i can distribuite a "clean" package.

Directories I need to delete follow this path:

```
views
  `- {directoryName1}
      `- tmpl
         `- index.html
  `- {directoryName2}
   .... and son on ....
```

Only the directoryName changes everytime, excepts that everything remains the same.
I tried with this ant task, but it didn't work:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${buildDir}/free">
       <exclude name="**/*" />
       <include name="**/tmpl/index.html"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

any help?

Comment: maybe this question can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232943/how-to-exclude-a-directory-from-ant-fileset-based-on-directories-contents

Comment: it's interesting, but my index.html file is in every directory. i need to delete those directories which contains ONLY a file with index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a combination of [resourcecount](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/resourcecount.html) and condition checks. I use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/) , but you have to include additional jars.

```
<project name="blah" basedir="." default="conditionally.clean">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
    <macrodef name="m.clean">
        <attribute name="dir.todelete"/>
        <sequential>
            <local name="count.files"/>
            <resourcecount property="count.files">
                <fileset dir="@{dir.todelete}">
                    <exclude name="index.html"/>
                </fileset>
            </resourcecount>

            <if>
                <equals arg1="${count.files}" arg2="0"/>
                <then>
                    <echo message="will delete dir @{dir.todelete}"  />
                </then>
                <else>
                       <echo message="will not delete dir @{dir.todelete}"  />
                </else>
            </if>

        </sequential>

    </macrodef>

    <target name="conditionally.clean">
        <m.clean dir.todelete="etc/demo2"/>
        <m.clean dir.todelete="etc/demo1"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

You can construct a "foreach" (requires ant-contrib)  to get all directories and call above macro...

(I guess a [custom task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html) or a [embedded script](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/09/20/using-javascript-make-apache-ant-less-painful) may be much cleaner than the build.xml ... )

Comment: nice solution, I too believe, that a custom task would be much easier