# Exclude java files when compiling an android library using ant

Tags: android, ant, build

I have an android library project which is build using ant. Everything works fine, but I have some test java files there that I do not want to be included in the generated jar file, anybody know how to make that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fi it adding the following lines in the build.xml of my android project:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <jar destfile="bin/myLibrary.jar">
        <zipfileset src="bin/classes.jar" excludes="com/my/package** com/something/unittest/**"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

This will remove the unwanted files and update the jar file

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio/Gradle allows you to specify classes to exclude from the build; in Android Studio you can exclude classes by editing the `build.gradle` file and adding a custom `SourceSet`. Something like this:

```
android
{
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.4"

    defaultConfig
    {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        packageName "org.google.home"
        testPackageName "org.google.home.test"
    }
    sourceSets
    {
        main
        {
            java
            {
                exclude '**/ClassToExclude.java'
            }
        }
        androidTest
        {
            java
            {
                exclude '**/TestforClassToExclude.java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see above, you can exclude both test files (located in you project test directory) and standard source files.

**EDIT**

For `ant` you can use something similiar, known as a `fileset` so specify files that should be exluded from the build. The user manual has an excellent section that describes how to accomplish this: 
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html.

`ant` also provides an `<exclude>` tag that you can use to specify files to exclude:

```
<exclude name="**/dir_name_to_exclude/**" />
```

There is also a stackoverflow post that discusses a similar issue: [How to exclude a directory from ant fileset, based on directories contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232943/how-to-exclude-a-directory-from-ant-fileset-based-on-directories-contents)

Comment: I can not use android studio because of the NDK :( so everything is set up for ant