# Exclude directory and js minification with Ant

Tags: javascript, java, xml, ant

I want to use `ant` for `js` and `css` minification at time of building the project. Please find below directory structure of my project:

[image: directory structure]

Here, scripts directory has multiple directories. 
I want to exclude directory named "Libraries" in scripts dirctory from `ant` task.

The dirctories other than "Libraries" has `js` files. And I want to include these `js` files in `ant` minification task.

Please find below my `build.xml`:

```
<project name="ITV" default="doMinification">
    <property name="webroot.dir" value="webapp/" /> 
    <target name="doMinification" depends="minifyjs" />

    <tstamp>
        <format property="TODAY_MY" pattern="yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"  locale="en,UK" />
    </tstamp>

    <!-- Minify JS -->
    <target name="minifyjs">                
        <apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="webapp/scripts/" verbose="true">
            <fileset id="jsFiles" dir="webapp/scripts/">
                <exclude name="webapp/scripts/Libraries/" />                
                <include name="**/*.js"/>                   
            </fileset>
            <arg line="-jar"/>
            <arg path="yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
            <srcfile/>
            <arg line="-o"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="**/*.js" to="*-min-${TODAY_MY}.js" />
            <targetfile/>
        </apply>            
    </target>
</project>
```

**How to exclude a specific directory and include other directories with its files in `ant` javascript minification task ?**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232943/how-to-exclude-a-directory-from-ant-fileset-based-on-directories-contents)

There is this answer:

```
<exclude name="**/dir_name_to_exclude/**" />
```

For your case:

```
<exclude name="**/Libraries/**" />
```

eg:

```
 <target name="minifyjs">                
        <apply executable="java" parallel="false" dest="webapp/scripts/" verbose="true">
            <fileset id="jsFiles" dir="webapp/scripts/">
                <exclude name="**/Libraries/**" />                
                <include name="**/*.js"/>                   
            </fileset>
            <arg line="-jar"/>
            <arg path="yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
            <srcfile/>
            <arg line="-o"/>
            <mapper type="glob" from="**/*.js" to="*-min-${TODAY_MY}.js" />
            <targetfile/>
        </apply>            
    </target>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @CodeLama- Thanks for the answer. I tried this but nothing happened.